# Why the background is different when I css a div?

Tags: html, css, background-image

Why is the background different when I style the div?

Here is my code. If I delete my css for the div, the background would immediately change. Does anybody know why? Thanks so much!

```
<style>
    html {
      font-size: 10px;
      background: url('./background.jpg') bottom center;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .keys {                  
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      min-height: 100vh;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="keys"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: the height of html become 0 so cover will not have the same effect

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following css:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Please note that your question is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

This makes it harder for us to help you.